# AWS S3 bucket changes are not reflected on my domain

Tags: html, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have two buckets `mywesbite.com` and `www.mywebsite.com`.

I have done the following -

1. Made the bucket `mywesbite.com` public with the following code -

```
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "AddPerm",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action": "s3:GetObject",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::mywebsite.com/*"
        }
    ]
}
```

2. Set the `index.html` file as the index document

I can now see my website loading, however this is only when I click the **endpoint** url - http://mywebsite.com.s3-website.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com

Of course my actual website is simply https://mywesbsite.com/ - yet I do not see any of my files being rendered here.

Is there something I'm missing?? It's all good having a working endpoint,  but I need to see my files rendered on my actual domain.

**Added** a picture of my route 53 settings below

[image]

Comment: Have you enabled static web hosting?

Comment: @alex067 yes I have

Comment: What have you configured in Amazon Route 53, or where ever your DNS name is managed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to create an alias record in your hosted zone for the domain "mywebsite.com" to point to the S3 bucket.

Remember though that there are some restrictions:
The S3 bucket must have the same name as your domain name.
The domain name has to be registered via route 53

Ofcourse you need to own the domain name "mywebsite.com" Just having an S3 bucket doesn't mean you own a domain name.

Comment: All of the above are done. Domain owned, alias record created in hosted zone, and the names are the same. I am totally lost. It's just fustrating because I cans see my wesbite working, but **only** on `http://mywesbite.com.s3-website.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com/`

Comment: Can you share what you have put in for the record name for the alias record?

Comment: this - s3-website.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com

Comment: you have to put just the bucket name for the record name, you dont need to include the actual link

Comment: The alias is not configured correctly. It wouldn't be an issue from S3 because, as you have said, you can access the bucket publicly with the s3 url. 

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/DeveloperGuide/RoutingToS3Bucket.html

Make sure you have followed the instructions below exactly. There is a route 53 misconfiguration going on.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I will have a look at that!